# Spreadsheet : Split text into predefined column

Tags: google-sheets

Please look at this sheet. 
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1gecstRTRdevMlvWsNdp0WZr1da2WZjwRt7cn2LRI7iA/edit?usp=sharing

Been on this for days, looked everywhere to no avail.

I have a group name in column C, separated with "/". In M3 I have a split formula, which will split the group in C into individual name and add a prefix to each. Works great. However, there are other data in between the names that's going to be pasted / entered. Therefore, I need the result to be shown in each 4 columns (yellow one), not next to each other like the current formula.

How to split C3 so that the result will be shown in each 4 columns ?
Note : column C can have 20 names at most.

Edit : Please spare the grammar of the sheet. I'm merely converting the data from my language into English while keeping the formula / cell intact, so it will look sluggish.

Comment: Noticed that you are using delimiter " / " (space - forward slash - space). So this splits "/ Note 7 /" into "Note" and "7" . Just wanted to check if this is what you want to happen?

Comment: Unfortunately it seems to me that you can't do it with a formula because an array formula will not expand if there is already data in some of the columns. Two possible alternatives (1) Copy the split output and the existing data across into a new sheet or (2) Use a script to do it

Comment: @Tom Sharpe Thank you for pointing out the "Note 7" issue. I corrected the formula.

Comment: @Tom Sharpe That sheet is just pseudo data, I will copy the formula data and paste its value elsewhere, then add the Wt, Pr and St. Hence I only need it to work. It is possible to just copy and paste the value of the current formula and insert columns in between them... But I want to automate the process for later use. Though of using `=QUERY(ARRAYFORMULA(.....),"Select Col1, Col1, Col1, Col1")` to expand 4 columns, then after I paste it I can just delete data of column 2,3,4 but unfortunately, query don't want me to use more than 1 Col1 in its query statement.. ugh. What a pain.

Comment: What if... use your split formula, populate the 20 columns. Then insert/create four columns, side-by-side and to the left of the 20 columns; link cell values in the four columns to the relevant columns in the 20-column group. Then _hide_ the 20-column group - all that appears on screen is the four columns. A variation... if you need access to the 20-column group, then put them on a separate sheet, and put your four columns on the main sheet, but still linked to the relevant columns in the 20-column group.

Comment: @Tedinoz Alright, I will use your method. It good enough for my situation. Thank you.